# When is $H_i(X,Y)\cong H_i(X/Y)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For orientable manifolds,for what $X$ and $Y\not=\varnothing$ does this isomorphism hold true?

Comment: What does the $Y$ in $H_i(X, Y)$ denote? In other words, what's the definition of that homology?

Comment: Relative Homology, assume it is over $G=\mathbb{Z}/(2)$.

Comment: Do you mean $X/Y$ on the right (i.e., collapsing $Y$ to a point)?

Comment: Heh, yeah that is what I meant, thanks.

Comment: I assume you want something more specific to manifolds than "$(X,Y)$ is a good pair", i.e. $Y$ is a nonempty closed subspace of $X$ that is a deformation retract of some neighborhood in $X$. In the smooth category, we can take $Y$ to be any properly embedded submanifold of $X$ (since these are deformation retracts of tubular neighborhoods).

Comment: @squirrel I was really just looking for some conditions through which this holds, because I am having trouble shaking the difference between these two at times.